# Pause foreach and continue

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, mysqli

I'm trying to loop data from a api and then post these values to a MySQL db.

something like this:

```
$values = json_decode(file_get_contents("my-json-file"));

$SQL = new mysqli(SQL_HOST, SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, DB_NAME);
$SQL->autocommit(FALSE);

foreach($values As $item)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('".$item->value1."', '".$item->value2.";)";
    $SQL->query($query);
    if(!$SQL->commit())
    {
        echo "ERROR ON INSERT: [" . $query . "]<hr/>";
    }
}
$SQL->close();
```

Since the loop is too fast, the SQL can't catch up. (Yea!) 
I would then need something like this:

```
foreach($values As $item)
{
    /**** STOP/PAUSE LOOP ****/

    $query = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('".$item->value1."', '".$item->value2.";");
    $SQL->query($query);
    if($SQL->commit())
    {
        /**** START THE LOOP AGAIN ****/
    }
    else
    {
        echo "ERROR ON INSERT: [" . $query . "]<hr/>";
    }
}
```

Or how should I do this the right way?

EDIT: It inserts random posts every time.

EDIT 2: This is just example code. It does escape and all that, and yes the semi colon is wrong here but since so many commented on it i will not change it. This was not the problem in the real case.
I tried to run it on another server and there it worked. The problem was fixed by restarting MAMP.

Comment: What do you mean by "loop is too fast, the SQL can't catch up"?  What's the *real* issue here?

Comment: `while (!$SQL->commit()) {}` ??

Comment: "loop is too fast, the SQL can't catch up.." you are too funny..

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you determine that "loop is too fast" and that SQL can't "catch up"?

Comment: Well, that's my suggestion. It just inserts some of the values, it's like it did'nt have the time to do the insert until the next value was about to be inserted?

Comment: Why are you performing commit on every iteration? Can't you just do the commit when the loop is done? And why are you not using prepared statements?

Comment: How would i do it? in the loop do something like $query .= "THE NEW QUERY;"; and when it finish to loop it would do all of them? Last time i tried mysqli couldn't do multiple queries.

Comment: I don't see how anything is being inserted because your query has a syntax error, you're missing a closing single quote at the end, and what is that semicolon doing within the parenthesis? Also you need to use a prepared statement or escape the values to avoid SQL Injection or the query breaking due to single quotes within the values.

Comment: @gubbfett: With `autocommit` off, it means the queries are ran, but the database isn't really altered.  When `commit()` is ran *all* the changes are pushed to the database.

Comment: @MrCode: Wow. Can't believe I missed that.  That's gotta be the issue here.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your idea that the loop runs too fast for MySQL to keep up is completely totally wrong. The `$SQL->query()` call will wait for the MySQL to return a response before proceeding, so the loop won't run any faster than MySQL is responding.

Now onto the actual problem.... your query:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('".$item->value1."', '".$item->value2.";)";
```

There's a semi-colon in there at the end, after `value2` which is invalid. I guess you intended to type a quote mark there? The semi-colon will be causing all your queries to fail and throw errors.

This may be the cause of your problem but you haven't got any error checking in there, so you won't know. Add some error checking to your code after calling the query; even if the query is right, it's still possible to get errors, and your code should check for them. See the examples on this manual page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Finally, since you're using the mysqli API, it's worth mentioning that your code would be a lot better and probably more secure if you used prepared statements. See the examples in PHP manual here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

[EDIT]

Another possible reason your query is failing is that you're not escaping the input values. If any of the input values contains a quote character (or any other character that is illegal in SQL) then the query will fail. In addition, this problem makes your code vulnerable to a SQL injection hacking attack.

You need to escape your input using `$SQL->real_escape_string()` OR by changing your query to use prepared statements (as recommended above).

Comment: Yea. It's fixed. Se "Edit 2". :)

Comment: fair enough. My other points still hold: PHP loop is *not* outpacing mySQL; you should add error checking; and using prepared statements will improve your code.

Comment: @gubbfett - please see my edit at the end of the answer. This is also an important point to take note of.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is inside the loop, which means that the loop will wait until your query finished executing before it continue, php code is processed in order...

Comment: Well, it doesn't wait? I've tried to echo all the querys in the loop and manually insert them and that works, so there's nothing wrong with the query or something.

Comment: Yes it does, seem like your error/mistake/problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Well, it just inserts random posts every time.

Answer (score 0):

Has @phpalix said, PHP goes in order, and waits for the previous action to finish.

I think you SQL is wrong. Try replacing your INSERT with this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('".$item->value1."', '".$item->value2."');";
```

And don't forget to run at least **mysql_real_escape_string** for each variable, for security measures.

Answer (score 0):

As many of the answers and comments say, it does not continue until the SQL is done. The problem was in my local apache/mysql server. It was fixed by restarting it. Yes, stupid post.

Comment: glad you solved the problem. Please do take note of the points raised by the comments and the answers here, because a lot of them are very good points, even if they aren't directly relevant to the problem.